# Is it ok to ask here if it's alright to ask a particular question in math.SE?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, meta

Let $Q$ be a question.

Suppose someone is unsure if $Q$ fits math.SE, and instead of getting negative votes/ $Q$ immediately closed, he decides to ask if it's okay to ask that question, here.

Is this normally accepted (know that if it's not, this question is breaking the rules, hah!)?

Comment: This makes me think we need a meta meta math.

Comment: And a meta meta meta math, $\cdots$

Comment: If you browse a bit through questions tagged ([meta-tag:allowed-questions]), you will find many questions like: "Are the questions from this area/of this type allowed on MSE?" As far as I remember, it is much rarer to ask on meta about a specific question, but maybe you can find some such posts. The two questions which are currently tagged [allowed-questions+specific-question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/allowed-questions+specific-question) are somewhat similar, but in those cases, the questions had already been posted (here or on another site) before asking on meta.

Comment: Worst case scenario, your question on meta is downvoted, closed and deleted. Unlike main, this carries no negative consequence for you that I know of.

Comment: Also, you should have asked if it is appropriate to ask on meta if it's ok to ask here if it's alright to ask a particular question, first.

Answer (score 8):

People seem to do this all the time, so I'm pretty sure it's OK:

- [Are cryptography questions allowed to be asked here?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1928/are-cryptography-questions-allowed-to-be-asked-here?rq=1)
- [Are mathematical translations on-topic?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22645/are-mathematical-translations-on-topic)
- Really, the entire [allowed-questions](/questions/tagged/allowed-questions) tag.